# How to find the sum of 2 columns of an excel and display it in a 3rd column using UIPATH?

Tags: excel, datatable, uipath

I want to read an excel file which have 2 columns with a few rows (integer values). I need to add a 3rd column in the excel and find the sum of the 1st 2 columns in that 3rd one. need to do this in UIPATH.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how you can achieve this:

1. Use of DataTable. So you first read your Excel file by using an Excel Application Scope activity with Read Range, then for each row read (the For Each Row activity), you use an Assign activity to get the sum of row(0) and row(1), the values of the first and second items in the row, and save it to a variable; lastly, write the value in this variable back to the Worksheet at the next column at `("C" + rowNumber)` e.g. C1, C2, C3.
2. Write straight to the Excel Worksheet at the next column (let's say, column C), with the formula; e.g. write your Excel file by using an Excel Application Scope activity with For Each Row and Write Cell, the content can be set to something like `"=SUM(A" + rowNumber + ":B" + rowNumber + ")"`.

+For the row number, you can initialize a counter outside of the For Each Row activity, and Assign it with a value of 1, at the end of each for-each, increase it by 1.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Debashish Great to hear that helps mate, if you like it could you please accept my answer by any chance?